# Simulate Windows directory path for a logo?

Tags: 17.10

I am a developer using Apache FOP (https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) on Ubuntu. The system I am developing for will run on a Windows server, and because of this I need to hard code the URL of a logo. When I run the code on Linux I get error (SEVERE: Image not found. URI: C:\XML\XSL\Style\logo.png. (No context info available))

Is it possible to somehow simulate this path: "C:\XML\XSL\Style\logo.png" ?

Comment: What is a FOP? Why do you need to hardcode instead of using a config file?

Comment: you could try wine

Comment: FOP = https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Comment: You need a relative path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217517/fop-how-to-specify-image-src-relative-path

Comment: Good suggestion Rinzwind, but I can only edit the XSL files, and not the other code because they are handeled by another company. It's because of them I have to use the Windows path.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\XML\XSL\Style\logo.png` in Linux would just be the name of a file:

```
$ touch 'C:\XML\XSL\Style\logo.png'
$ ls
C:\XML\XSL\Style\logo.png
```

Just create it in whichever directories your program runs in, so that when it tries to access the file, it will be treated as a relative path to a file and taken from the current directory.

Comment: This worked, but didn't solve my problem.. I still get the same error message.